# What is the meaning of "estaba más allá de todo"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, modismos

In Gabriel García Marquez's "Memorias de mis putas tristes", the following sentence is unknown in meaning to me, even the English translation, which I do not understand:

> Spanish: Rosa Cabarcas, cómo no, estaba más allá de todo.
>
> English translation (Grossman): Rosa  Cabarcas,  of  course,  was  above  everything.

Does "más allá de todo" convey a certain idiomatic meaning in Spanish or is it just understood as is?

Comment: No, I think your translation is just fine and the meaning is basically the same.

Answer (score 3):

Through Google Books I could find the book and read this sentence in its context. I am copying here a little excerpt for the benefit of anyone reading this:

> Fui el perdedor absoluto en una sola jugada: me quedé sin Delgadina, sin Rosa Cabarcas y sin mis últimos ahorros. Sin embargo, oí el timbre del teléfono una vez, dos veces, tres, y por fin ella: ¿A ver? No me salió la voz. Colgué. Me eché en la hamaca, tratando de serenarme con la lírica ascética de Satie, y sudé tanto que el lienzo quedó empapado. Hasta el día siguiente no tuve el valor de llamar.
>
> - Bueno, mujer -dije con voz firme-. Hoy sí.
>
> **Rosa Cabarcas, cómo no, estaba más allá de todo**. Ay, mi sabio triste, suspiró con su ánimo invencible, te pierdes dos meses y sólo vuelves para pedir ilusiones. Me contó que no había visto a Delgadina desde hacía más de un mes (...)

From what I see, here "estaba más allá de todo" has the meaning that this woman has a deeper understanding of the situation than the person telling the story.

To my understanding, the main character was back then a young man who had some pretensions towards Delgadina; however, his hesitations made it impossible for him to get any further. And Rosa Cabarcas, the kind-of-celestina (matchmaker) is perfectly conscious of the situation and addresses him with a mix of condescension and affection.

I have found some references of the sentence *estar más allá de todo* in some religious books, referring God as being beyond everything. So the sentence in terms of construction can be taken from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation seems perfect to me. In fact, another way of saying the same is *estar por encima de todo*, which is the literal translation of your English version. This expression is [included in the DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=F6SsXHC):

> **por encima de todo**
>
> 1. loc. adv. A pesar de cualquier obstáculo.

The meaning could be that no opinion from others, no laws, no events and no obstacles can affect you (or your decisions) in any way.